# CSS Flexible Table Headers

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, flexbox

I'm having trouble shrinking the width of the `.rowHeader1` when the table is resized.

`.rowHeader1` and `.rowHeader2` are wrapped within a flex container.  `.rowHeader1` should grow and shrink but should never be smaller than `60px` in width while `.rowHeader2` should always remain `60px` in width.

Without removing the Table semantic tags, is it possible to make the row headers flex properly?

```css
body {
    background-color: #444;
}

table {
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
}

tr, th, td {
    border: 1px solid white;
}

tbody td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

tbody th {
    display: flex;
}

:root {
    --MIN-SIZE: 60px;
}

.rowHeader1 {
    flex: 1 1 var(--MIN-SIZE);
    border: 1px solid red;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-align: left;
}

.rowHeader2 {
    flex: 0 0 var(--MIN-SIZE);
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column Header</th>
            <th>Data</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div class="rowHeader1">Row Header 1 Row Header 1</div>
                <div class="rowHeader2">RH 2</div>
            </th>
            <td>
                Some Table Data Some Table Data Some Table Data
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `flex-shrink` value of `.rowHeader1` to `0` and set it's width to 60px, it will grow to fill the space but won't shrink smaller than 60px:

```css
body {
  background-color: #444;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

tr,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

tbody td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

tbody th {
  display: flex;
}

:root {
  --MIN-SIZE: 60px;
}

.rowHeader1 {
  flex: 1 0 var(--MIN-SIZE);
  width: 60px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-align: left;
}

.rowHeader2 {
  flex: 0 0 var(--MIN-SIZE);
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column Header</th>
      <th>Data</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class="rowHeader1">Row Header 1 Row Header 1</div>
        <div class="rowHeader2">RH 2</div>
      </th>
      <td>
        Some Table Data Some Table Data Some Table Data
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```